# Correct way to fix capture conversion in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion

Having a hierarchical model which uses inheritance and generics in collection, I have a compilation error related to [capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html):

```
CaptureConversion.java:16: error: incompatible types: NodeModel cannot be converted to CAP#1
    treeModel.getNodes().set(0, primaryNode);
                                ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends PublicNodeModel from capture of ? extends PublicNodeModel
```

The only way I was able to surpass this error was via following conversion method:

```java
private static <T extends PublicNodeModel> T convert(PublicNodeModel node) {
    return (T) node;
}
```

This conversion looks quite silly to me, so my question is **if there is some "correct" way how to deal with this kind of conversion in Java?**

---

The model and code causing this error is following (a full [runnable example](https://github.com/sw-samuraj/blog-capture-conversion/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/swsamuraj/capture/CaptureConversion.java) on GitHub).

A simplified model (e.g. no getters/setters etc.):

```java
class PublicTreeModel {
    List<? extends PublicNodeModel> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}

class TreeModel extends PublicTreeModel {}

class PublicNodeModel {}

class NodeModel extends PublicNodeModel {}
```

Usage causing the compilation error:

```java
TreeModel treeModel = Fixture.createModel();
int index = Fixture.indexOfPrimaryNode(treeModel.getNodes());
NodeModel primaryNode = (NodeModel) treeModel.getNodes().get(index);

// following two lines won't compile
treeModel.getNodes().set(index, treeModel.getNodes().get(0));
treeModel.getNodes().set(0, primaryNode);
```

Usage with aforementioned fix (the `convert()` method):

```java
// this will compile & run
treeModel.getNodes().set(index, convert(treeModel.getNodes().get(0)));
treeModel.getNodes().set(0, convert(primaryNode));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class PublicTreeModel {
    List<? extends PublicNodeModel> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

You're not *supposed* to be able to put anything into that list, other than literal `null`. This type says "it's *some* subclass of `PublicNodeModel`, I just don't know which": because the compiler doesn't know which subclass to allow, it prevents you adding any elements. You're only supposed to consume elements from this list, not provide elements to it.

---

In this specific case, you're effectively just swapping elements around in the list, so there's a simple solution:

```
TreeModel treeModel = Fixture.createModel();
int index = Fixture.indexOfPrimaryNode(treeModel.getNodes());
Collections.swap(treeModel.getNodes(), 0, index);
```

That is: even if you don't know the exact expected subtype of the elements in `treeModel.getNodes()`, you know that the element you're trying to put back in was taken out of the list; so it's type-safe (or, at least, no less type-safe than it was already).

---

In a more general case, there are two other solutions: firstly, remove the wildcard, so that the list accepts *any* subclass of `PublicNodeModel`:

```
class PublicTreeModel {
    List<PublicNodeModel> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This may not be acceptable if you actually want to be able to rely on the elements of `nodes` being specifically `NodeModel`s.

A second approach would be to add a type parameter to the class for the type of elements to hold in the list:

```
class PublicTreeModel<T extends PublicNodeModel> {
    List<T> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In the context of the code you show which has the compilation error, the second approach might become:

```
class TreeModel extends PublicTreeModel<NodeModel> {}

TreeModel treeModel = Fixture.createModel();
int index = Fixture.indexOfPrimaryNode(treeModel.getNodes());

NodeModel primaryNode = treeModel.getNodes().get(index);

treeModel.getNodes().set(index, treeModel.getNodes().get(0));
treeModel.getNodes().set(0, primaryNode);
```

Comment: Hm. The second general solution looks promising. I will check if it works in my context (the example is highly simplified).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force the matter, one idea is to make a cast:

```
 ( (List<PublicNodeModel>)treeModel.getNodes()).set(0, primaryNode);
```

at a cost of an `unchecked or unsafe operations` warning, but this is, of course, not recommanded. @Andy Turner's answer is the way to go.